# How do I give a Box2d Kinematic body a predefined curved path

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I'm new to using Box2d and really can't find a consistent answer to my question so please excuse me.

I'm writing a game for the iPhone -- who isn't these days -- and I'm using Cocos2d and Box2D.  I have objects that move around in the game and I would like to give them a more of a curved path.  From my studies I know that I should use body of type b2_kinematicBody which allows me to change the linear velocity every tick and keeps them from colliding with my other flying bodies.  I do understand that if I know my current position (x,y) and my next position in the step (x1,y1) I would be able to compute the vector for velocity.  Does anybody have a good way to give an object a defined curved path?  I'm thinking it has to be some kind of parametric equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at bezier curves. After curve defenition you can compute the derivative (it's easy for bezier) and use it as a velocity for your body

Comment: For closer, the first derivative of the bezier curve is working great!  Many thanks!

Comment: Just to verify I'm going down the right path, to get a constant velocity as the body is moving on the curve I do the follow. After finding velocity vector, I normalize which gives me a constant speed and then multiple by some factor if i want it to move faster on the curve.  Does this seem correct for this kind of simulation.

Comment: @Aaron: No, it does not. I don't know a simple way for moving with a constant speed along bezier. I suggest you to split the curve programmatically into lines (more lines - more smooth movement). It's easy to control speed if moving on the line

Answer (score -1):

OH whats the game called? sounds like a good one. have you looked into maybe just doing that in version 2.0

Comment: I would really like to be able to give a curved path and not just a line.  It will increase the complexity by an order of magnitude.